# How to let finger track by UIResponder with ios-chart?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I want to track the finger when using the Chart on mobile, so I use UIResponder and override the touchBegan, touchMoved and touchEnded as follow.

```
var startLocation: CGPoint?
var totalDistance: CGFloat = 0


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    if let touch = touches.first {
        totalDistance = 0
        startLocation = touch.location(in: self.chart1)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    if let startLocation = startLocation, let touch = touches.first {
        let currentLocation = touch.location(in: self.chart1)
        let dX = currentLocation.x - startLocation.x
        let dY = currentLocation.y - startLocation.y
        self.totalDistance += sqrt(pow(dX, 2) + pow(dY, 2))
        self.startLocation = currentLocation

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    print("Total distance: \(totalDistance)")
}
```

And I build a view named chart1 to present chart view. I could calculate the distance at the space outside the chart1. But I couldn't calculate the distance when I swiped just on the chart.
Could anyone give me some suggestion?
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where is `UISwipeGesture` ?

Comment: Sorry, I got some mistakes. Correct one is UIResponder. Thank you!